# &bull; not working in sandbox

Tags: visualforce

This small piece of code is messing me up:  The Visualforce page works well in production but fails to show the proper output in **Sandbox**. In sandbox, the page shows "`&bull;`" as `&#8226`, and `</br>` tags do not work.

The output in sandbox is `&#8226; Another user has started working on this incident. Please Choose another incident <br/>`

My page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<style> 
        body 
        { 
            font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
            font-weight:regular;
            font-size:12px;
            color:red;
        }            
</style>
   <apex:outputText value="{!IF((Case.OwnerId != $User.Id), '&bull; Another user has started working on this incident. Please Choose another incident <br/>','&bull;  Review customer account  (related incidents, valid email address, phone number and address)<br/>
    &bull; Merge any related incidents<br/>
    &bull; Enter incident reasons for all contacts (review customer comments to ensure accuracy)<br/>
    &bull; Decide if follow up will be needed and check all required boxes<br/>
    &bull; If Hawaii or international address choose proper button<br/>')}" />
```

Comment: You need to use `escape="false"` parameter and wrap the long text with a close tag `</apex:outputText>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the attribute escape="false" to the outputText

```
 <apex:outputText value=".....your text including markup...." escape="False" />
```

Comment: If this resolved you issue, please mark this as your Answer. It is important for us to keep our answer rate high.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. And more internet points for me! Glad that answer helped you Bharadwaj.